# What was the TV show where they entered VR by placing a phone on a computer?

Tags: story-identification

I remember several years ago (90s, likely) there was this TV show about this guy (and later some friends) who accidentally discovered VR or something, after talking to someone on the phone, then placed the phone on top of a computer thingy. I think the first episode had the guy, when in VR, on a bus with creepy people. He also had to touch a specific object in order to get out.
I was thinking about this recently. Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The show title was *VR5*.  The protagonist was actually a woman hacker who first entered VR5 (five-sense VR) by accidentally putting the phone to her ear when it was connected by acoustic coupled modem to a remote computer.

The VR world was extra-vivid colors, distorted sound, and surreal images.  I don't recall her having to touch something specific to exit, but there was something she had to do to disconnect from the remote network.

Comment: Yeah, there was always an exit-object (usually colored a specific color IIRC) that she had to find (or accidentally always found) to kick her out.

Comment: I won't argue, just didn't recall that detail from a one-season show that ran thirty years or so ago.